# Division with returning quotient and remainder

Tags: go

I try to migrate from Python to Golang. I currently do research some math operations and wonder about how can I get both quotient and remainder value with result of a division. I'm going to share below an equivalent of Python code.

```
hours, remainder = divmod(5566, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
print('%s:%s' % (minutes, seconds))
# 32:46
```

Above will be my aim. Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Integer division plus modulus accomplishes this.

```
func divmod(numerator, denominator int64) (quotient, remainder int64) {
    quotient = numerator / denominator // integer division, decimals are truncated
    remainder = numerator % denominator
    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rimqraYE2B

Edit: Definitions

**Quotient**, in the context of integer division, is the number of *whole* times the numerator goes into the denominator.  In other words, it is identical to the decimal statement: `FLOOR(n/d)`

**Modulo** gives you the *remainder* of such a division.  The modulus of a numerator and denominator will always be between 0 and d-1 (where d is the denominator)

Comment: Your solution was crystal clear. It was distressed me that not to have built-in one like Python.

Answer (score 33):

if you want a one-liner,

```
quotient, remainder := numerator/denominator, numerator%denominator
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 32 bit number, you can use one of these:

```
package main
import "math/bits"

func main() {
   { // example 1
      var n uint = 4294967295
      q, r := bits.Div(0, n, 2)
      println(q == n / 2, r == 1)
   }
   { // example 2
      var n uint32 = 4294967295
      q, r := bits.Div32(0, n, 2)
      println(q == n / 2, r == 1)
   }
}
```

If you have a 64 bit number, you can do it like this:

```
package main
import "math/bits"

func main() {
   var n uint64 = 18446744073709551615
   q, r := bits.Div64(0, n, 2)
   println(q == n / 2, r == 1)
}
```

If you have something larger than 64 bit, you can do it like this:

```
package main
import "math/bits"

func main() {
   q, r := bits.Div64(1, 0, 2)
   println(q == 9223372036854775808, r == 0)
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits#Div
- https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits#Div32
- https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits#Div64

Comment: What I like about this answer is that it's probably more performant since I suspect "bits" is smart enough to do the work efficiently whereas the other answers look like multiple math operations.

Answer (score 0):

I did this function maybe it's what you are looking for.

```
//QuotientAndRemainderF32 Computes the integer quotient and the remainder of the inputs. This function rounds floor(x/y) to the nearest integer towards -inf.
func QuotientAndRemainderF32(x, y float32) (Remainder, Quotient float32) {
    Quotient = float32(math.Floor(float64(x / y)))
    Remainder = x - y*Quotient
    return Remainder, Quotient
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question is not clear: are you looking for something equivalent to the Python `divmod` or just a function that returns the quotient and the reminder?

These solutions are not equivalent to the Python `divmod` since they return the reminder instead of the modulus. So, they do not work the same way with negative numbers.

In Python `divmod(-7, 4)` returns `-2, 1`.
The answers here return `-1, 3`.

My suggestion is

```
func DivMod(n, d int64) (q, r int64) {
    q = n / d
    r = n % d

    // the numerator or the denominator is negarive (but not both)
    if r != 0 && n*d < 0 {
        q--
        r += d
    }
    return
}
```